# python pystfp using a corporate proxy

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I'm using pysftp to access an stfp. My script works fine when I'm off my corporate VPN. However, once I'm using my corporate VPN the script runs into the following error:

```
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you connect with any commandline/GUI SFTP client from your corporate VPN? If you can, what settings do you use?

Comment: No, I haven't done any of these. I'd need my IT department to give me local admin for commandline and set-up an SFTP client

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to implement something before verifying, if it is possible at all in the first place. And in general, you do not need admin privileges to use a command-line SFTP client. OpenSSH `sftp` is even part of Windows these days.